# How can I iterate through a python list with selenium performing a search for each item, scrape the data, and then search the next item

Tags: python, selenium

I have two lists of baseball players that I would like to scrape data for from the website fangraphs. I am trying to figure out how to have selenium search the first player in the list which would redirect to that players profile, scrape the data I am interested in, and then search the next player until each for loop is completed for the two lists. I have written other scrapers with selenium, but I haven't come across this situation where I need to perform a search, collect the data, then perform the next search, etc ...

Here is a smaller version of one of the lists:

```
batters = ['Freddie Freeman','Bryce Harper','Jesse Winker']
driver.get('https://www.fangraphs.com/')
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/header/div[3]/nav/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input')
search_box.click()
for batter in batters:
   search_box.send_keys(batter)
   search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

This will search all the names at once obviously, so I guess I'm trying to figure out how to code the logic of searching one by one but not performing the next search until I have collected the data for the previous search - any help is appreciated cheers

Comment: Do you need to use Selenium? There's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

With selenium, you would just have to iterate through the names, "type" it into the search bar, click/go to the link, scrape the stats, then repeat. You have set up to do that, you just need to add the scrape part. So something like:

```
batters = ['Freddie Freeman','Bryce Harper','Jesse Winker']
driver.get('https://www.fangraphs.com/')
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/header/div[3]/nav/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input')
search_box.click()
for batter in batters:
   search_box.send_keys(batter)
   search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

   ## CODE THAT SCRAPES THE DATA ##
   
   ## CODE THAT STORES IT SOMEWAY TO APPEND AFTER EACH ITERATION ##
```

However, they have an api which is a far better solution than Selenium. Why?

1. APIs are consistent. Parsing HTML with selnium and/or beautifulsoup is reliant on the html structure. If they ever change the layout of the website, it may crash as certain tags that used to be there may not be there anymore, or they may add certain tags and attributes to the html. But the underlying data that is rendered in the html will come from the api in a nice json format and that will rarely change unless they do a complete overhaul of the data structure
2. It's far more efficient and quicker. No need to have Selenium open a browser, search and load/render the content, that scrape, then repeat. You get the response in 1 request
3. You'll get far more data than you intended and (imo) is a good thing. I'd rather have more data and "trim" off what I don't need. Lots of the time you'll see very interesting and useful data that you otherwise wouldn't had known was there.

So I'm not sure what you are after specifically, but this will get you going. You'll have to sift through the `statsData` to figure out what you want, but if you tell me what you are after, I can help get that into a nice table for you. Or if you want to figure it out yourself, look up `pandas` and the `.json_normalize()` function with that. Parsing nested json can be tricky (but it's also fun ;-) )

**Code:**

```
import requests

# Get teamIds
def get_teamIds():
    team_id_dict = {}
    url = 'https://cdn.fangraphs.com/api/menu/menu-standings'
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
    for team in jsonData:
        team_id_dict[team['shortName']] = str(team['teamid'])
        
    return team_id_dict

# Get Player IDs
def get_playerIds(team_id_dict):
    player_id_dict = {}
    for team, teamId in team_id_dict.items():
        url = 'https://cdn.fangraphs.com/api/depth-charts/roster?teamid={teamId}'.format(teamId=teamId)
        jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
        print(team)
        for player in jsonData:
            if 'oPlayerId' in player.keys():
                player_id_dict[player['player']] = [str(player['oPlayerId']), player['position']]
            else:
                player_id_dict[player['player']] = ['N/A', player['position']]
                
    return player_id_dict


team_id_dict = get_teamIds()
player_id_dict = get_playerIds(team_id_dict)


batters = ['Freddie Freeman','Bryce Harper','Jesse Winker']
for player in batters:
    playerId = player_id_dict[player][0]
    pos = player_id_dict[player][1]
    url = 'https://cdn.fangraphs.com/api/players/stats?playerid={playerId}&position={pos}'.format(playerId=playerId, pos=pos)
    statsData = requests.get(url).json()
```

**Ouput: [Here's just a look at what you get](https://pastebin.com/7bjthQv1)**